# Bash script to traverse folder tree and extract files from bundles

Tags: bash, bundle

For years I have been using an OS X archive app that stores prior versions of documents in an OS X bundle.  This app is not compatible with Sierra, but I don't want to lose all of my file archives.

Here's the file folder structure:

```
Dir1
|--document_archive_1 <--has name of original document
|  --doc_version_1    <--has name in form: 20160301 180206 -0800
|  --doc_version_2    <--has name in form: 20151127 171422 -0800
|--document_archive_2
|  --doc_version_1    
|subdir1
|   --document_archive_3
|   subsubdir
etc.
```

Or, in words, each folder in the tree contains a combination of subfolders and OS X bundles that contain the archived document versions (and nothing else).  The bundle has as its file name the file name of the document whose archived versions are inside. The archive bundle has files whose names are date stamps.

What I want to do is to traverse the folder tree.  When I encounter an archive bundle, I want to:

1. create a folder whose name is the name of the archive bundle
2. move the archive bundle into the folder created in step 2
3. "unbundle" the archive bundle
4. rename the "unbundled" files with the name of the archive bundle plus the date stamp, stripping off the time zone offset

So, for example...for a Word document called "letter_to_dad.doc" an archive bundle is named "letter_to_dad.doc.synkarchive" and would look like this:

```
|letter_to_dad.doc.synkarchive
|--20160301 180206 -0800 <--this is a .doc file but has no extension
|--20151127 171422 -0800
```

What I want to end up with is:

```
|folder called 'letter_to_dad'
|--letter_to_dad 20160301 180206.doc
|--letter_to_dad 20151127 171422.doc
```

I have only done a little Bash script writing, and what I want to do is over my current head, so any help would be appreciated. I'm thinking that this shouldn't be that hard, but I may be naive about that...

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK bundles are just folders, so the following script should do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

bundle_root=${HOME}
out_root="/tmp"

function copy_bundle {
    bn="$(basename "$1")"
    bn=${bn%%.*}
    new_dir="${out_root}/${bn}"
    mkdir "${new_dir}" 2>/dev/null
    rsync -a "$1" "${new_dir}"
    find . -type f | xargs -I% mv % "${new_dir}/${bn}_$(echo % | sed -Ee 's,[[:space:]]+,_,g' -e 's,_(-|[[:alnum:]])+$,,')"
}

export out_root
export -f copy_bundle

find "${bundle_root}" -iname "*.bundle" -type d -exec bash -c 'copy_bundle "{}"' \;
```

Comment: Thanks.  Issues... (1) The stock OS X install doesn't have the realpath command.  I substituted readlink e, based on what I found on the net.  I'm not sure if they are truly equivalent. (2) all the mv commands resulted in "permission denied," although in checking the permissions, I am the owner.  The mv commands also resulted in weird names.  E.g. mv: rename ./CAMNER.QDF.synkarchive/20120609 153635 -0700 to /CMIOUnits__:  AND mv: rename ./CAMNER.QDF.synkarchive/20120609 153635 -0700 to /EDEL__:  AND mv: rename ./CAMNER.QDF.synkarchive/20120609 153635 -0700 to /AppleIntermediateCodec__:

Comment: Yeah, renaming wasn't implemented correctly. I've edited the script, now it should be fine.